# End session when home button is pressed by user - Android

Tags: android

At the moment i have multiple ways for the user to end a session on a webview. What i am struggling to do is - User session to end when home button is pressed (Cookies and cache cleared) so that user is logged out on app access the next time.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried ending the session in onPause() of your activity? note that onPause is called more often than when the activity is closed (e.g. screen rotation)

Comment: You cannot detect when the Home button is pressed. But you can use the Activity's lifecycle to have the same behavior. I would go with `onPause()` or `onStop()` https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html